# draw object with texture and circles in the same screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

i want to display object with texture and another one without texture

when i run my code only the another object drawn

here my code

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1200
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 800

void drawCircle(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat radius)
{
    GLfloat twicePi = 2.0f * 3.14;

    GLfloat circleVerticesX[363];
    GLfloat circleVerticesY[363];
    GLfloat circleVerticesZ[363];

    circleVerticesX[0] = x;
    circleVerticesY[0] = y;
    circleVerticesZ[0] = z;

    for (int i = 1; i < 363; i++)
    {
        circleVerticesX[i] = x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / 360));
        circleVerticesY[i] = y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / 360));
        circleVerticesZ[i] = z;
    }

    GLfloat allCircleVertices[(363) * 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 363; i++)
    {
        allCircleVertices[i * 3] = circleVerticesX[i];
        allCircleVertices[(i * 3) + 1] = circleVerticesY[i];
        allCircleVertices[(i * 3) + 2] = circleVerticesZ[i];
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, allCircleVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 363);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void draw(int x)
{
    GLfloat margin, radius, YP = 300;
    radius = (x <= 5 ? (0.25 * 0.8 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / x : (0.25 * 0.8 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / 5);
    margin = (x <= 5 ? (0.5 * 0.2 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / x : (0.5 * 0.2 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / 5);
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (i <= 5)
            drawCircle((i)*margin + 2 * radius * (i - 0.5) + 580, YP, 0, radius);
        else
            drawCircle((i - 5) * margin + 2 * radius * (i - 5.5) + 580, YP - 120, 0, radius);
    }
}

GLuint DrawImage(int turn)
{
    int width, height, nrChannels;

    GLuint texture;
    string location = "Pics/" + to_string(turn) + ".jpg";
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("Pics/1.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free(data);

    return texture;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Draw Circles", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        draw(2);
        GLuint texture;
        texture = DrawImage(2);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

i want to display both object in the same window

when i run only  circles drawn and another object disappeared

Comment: because i want to change this image every frame

Comment: Yup, reading comprehension fail on my part :(

Comment: You set your camera in the first quadrant `0, width, 0, height` but when you supply quad coordinates they are negative. I think you were trying to supply quad coords in NDC space but this only works when the matrices are identity.

Comment: thanks man this work <3

Comment: Oh man, where did you learn this OpenGL? Come on, it is about a time to start using modern OpenGL. You will be able to write much cleaner and robust apps. Also be careful with those stack arrays, you may hit a stack overflow.